# Font Awesome Icons do not align with text inside a Bulma menu

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, bulma

When font awesome icons are added to a Bulma navbar item, they align correctly to the text. However, when adding the same icon to a Bulma menu, they are misaligned. How do I correctly align icons with text in a Bulma menu without using custom CSS?

[image: Misaligned Icons inside menu]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <title>Test</title>
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.0/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    *:not(path):not(g) {
      color: hsla(210, 100%, 100%, 0.9) !important;
      background: hsla(210, 100%, 50%, 0.5) !important;
      outline: solid 0.05rem hsla(210, 100%, 100%, 0.5) !important;
      box-shadow: none !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
    <div class="navbar-menu">
      <div class="navbar-start">
        <a class="navbar-item"><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-book"></i></span><span>- Test Correctly Aligned</span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <aside class="menu">
    <ul class="menu-list">
      <li><a><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-book"></i></span><span>- Test Incorrectly aligned</span></a></li>
      <li><a><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-book"></i></span><span>- Test Incorrectly aligned</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The icons are 1.25rem, whereas the text is only 1rem - making them the same size is a quick and dirty fix.

Comment: Tried. Makes it worse.

Comment: Depends on what you mean - I did a manual edit of the span which contains the menu's text, to make it the same size as the icon, and they lined up. Since there's no class on that span, you'd have to add one or manually add a style attribute to each one. Or use a rule with `:not()`.

Comment: This gets it close: `.menu-list span:not(.icon){ font-size: 1.25rem; }` - not really familiar with Bulma (outside of DBZ, that is), or I'd suggest something better in an answer.

Comment: Its still misaligned a bit. Also changing the font size isn't an option.

Comment: Maybe this? `.menu-list li a { display: flex; align-items: top; }` - seems pretty close to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out the bulma [icon](https://bulma.io/documentation/elements/icon/) class isn't really compatible with newer font awesome version. The solution is to let fontawesome classes take over. After removing .icon class and adding fa-fw, the icons align perfectly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <title>Test</title>
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.0/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    *:not(path):not(g) {
      color: hsla(210, 100%, 100%, 0.9) !important;
      background: hsla(210, 100%, 50%, 0.5) !important;
      outline: solid 0.05rem hsla(210, 100%, 100%, 0.5) !important;
      box-shadow: none !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
    <div class="navbar-menu">
      <div class="navbar-start">
        <a class="navbar-item"><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-book"></i></span><span>- Test Correctly Aligned</span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <aside class="menu">
    <ul class="menu-list">
      <li><a><span class="fas fa-book fa-fw"></span><span>- Test Incorrectly aligned</span></a>
      <li><a><span class="fas fa-book fa-fw"></span><span>- Test Incorrectly aligned</span></a>
    </ul>
  </aside>
</body>

</html>
```